# Inference on bootstrap confidence intervals for VaR

Tags: risk-management, value-at-risk, bootstrapping

I have calculated the confidence intervals of the VaR for two assets using iid bootstrap. I compute VaR using historical simulation (non-parametric). So I have two bootstrap confidence intervals (in my case percentile intervals). How can I infer on them? For example, let's say that the two intervals are overlapped: can I say that they represent the same VaR (thus the same risk)? And if they are not overlapped? Do you know if there is some statistical test useful in this case?

Comment: If they overlap each other, you may say they are statistically the same, but if they do not overlap, then they are different and one must be wrong.

Comment: @Gordon: why would you say that if the confidence intervals do not overlap, one must be wrong? I am considering VaR on two different assets so it is possibe that the risk of one asset is statistically different from the risk of another asset. I do not undertand why one must be wrong.

Comment: I overlooked. they are not really related, and we can not tell which is wrong.